# when changing mesh in real time by three.js... (THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D)

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, mesh

I'm new to **three.js** and trying to change the mesh by clicking the button,
but I keep getting this error...

```
THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.
```

I found that type of the mesh(ShapeGeometry) that I'm trying to change is the 'object', which is the same with the baseline object(SphereGeometry).

My codes are like this:

**1. Baseline object (SphereGeometry)**

```
var Geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 15, 15);
var Material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: '#FFFFFF',
  wireframe: true
});

var compoCenter = new THREE.Mesh(Geometry, Material);
var compoLeft = new THREE.Mesh(Geometry, Material);
var compoRight = new THREE.Mesh(Geometry, Material);

compoCenter.position.set(0, 0, 0);
compoLeft.position.set(-80, 0, 30);
compoRight.position.set(80, 0, 30);

group.add(compoCenter);
group.add(compoLeft);
group.add(compoRight);

render();
scene.add(group);
```

**2. render() function**

`compoNew` is an object that is exported from another file and it defines a new geometry that I want to change into.

```
    function render() {
      // color rendering
      var userColor = document.querySelector('#userCustom').innerHTML;
      Material.color = new THREE.Color(userColor);
      
      // // Changing Geometry

      if (shape_heart_cnt % 2 != 0) {
        group.remove(compoCenter);
        group.remove(compoLeft);
        group.remove(compoRight);
        
        var compoCenterNew = compoNew;
        var compoLeftNew = compoNew;
        var compoRightNew = compoNew;

        scene.add(compoCenterNew);
        
        compoCenterNew.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        compoLeftNew.position.set(-80, 0, 30);
        compoRightNew.position.set(80, 0, 30);

      } else {
        group.add(compoCenter);
        group.add(compoLeft);
        group.add(compoRight);
      }
```

**3. New Geometry(ShapeGeometry) that I want to change into**

```
function decideShow(){
    const x = 0;
    const y = 0;

    const heartShape = new THREE.Shape();

    heartShape.moveTo( x + 5, y + 5 );
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 5, y + 5, x + 4, y, x, y );
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x - 6, y, x - 6, y + 7,x - 6, y + 7 );
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x - 6, y + 11, x - 3, y + 15.4, x + 5, y + 19 );
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 12, y + 15.4, x + 16, y + 11, x + 16, y + 7 );
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 16, y + 7, x + 16, y, x + 10, y );
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 7, y, x + 5, y + 5, x + 5, y + 5 );

    var GeometryNew = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(heartShape);

    var MaterialNew = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        wireframe: true
    });

    var compoNew = new THREE.Mesh(GeometryNew, MaterialNew);


    return compoNew
};

var compoNew = decideShow();
export { compoNew };
```

I think the point that I'm getting error is like the below (in render function). But I can't figure out why I'm getting `THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D` error.

```
scene.add(compoCenterNew);
```

Please Help me :(

Comment: Hey, make sure to upvote and accept if my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is showing because you are trying to add a 2D object (ShapeGeometry) to a 3D Scene. Other than that, you need to show your code for `compoNew` so we can see what went wrong while exporting/importing the object into the new file.